# Why ax.twinx() is causing this behaviour?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two datasets that I need to plot together and to label differently. Plotting them together in logarithmic scale is easy with one axis:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,10))

ax1.plot(x1, y1, c='gainsboro', linewidth=1.2, zorder=1)
ax1.scatter(x2, y2, s=60, facecolors='', edgecolors='k', zorder=2)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
```

[image]

The problem comes when I use `ax.twinx()` to duplicate the y axis and make them independent:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,10))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.plot(x1, y1, c='gainsboro', linewidth=1.2, zorder=1)
ax2.scatter(x2, y2, s=60, facecolors='', edgecolors='k', zorder=2)

plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
```

[image]

I don't understand why duplicating the axis is also causing the plot to ignore the logarithmic scale. Also, I don't see how the data in the second case is related to the two axis that is is showing.

Comment: `plt.yscale` sets only the scale of the current axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned by @Goyo, the problem comes from the fact that you are mixing [the Object-oriented syntax and the State-machine (pyplot) syntax](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related).

When using the state-machine synthax (`plt.xxx`) the commands affect the "current axes", which is usually the last created (in your second example, `ax2`). If you have several axes, it is generally easier to directly use the methods belonging [to the Axes class](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes):

```
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you Diziet and Goyo for your kind response :)

Comment: @cwasdwa If you can, try to get rid of the `plt.method()` style in your projects because it can become quite cryptic.